# Using standard output from C library in C++ application

Tags: c++, c, input, stream

I have code written in C, which I'm working towards making a library from which I can access functions from other languages.

I am presently writing a C++ client to this code, to figure out what changes are necessary to provide support for including my library into a C++ application.

Normally, the C-based binary analyzes some input, and it then outputs its data to `stdout` through a series of `fprintf` statements.

Is there a way to redirecting output from the relevant C functions sent to `stdout`?

I am not a C++ expert, but I think what I would like to do is provide a subclass of a C++ output stream buffer (`ostream` and `ofstream`?), which contains the same output that would otherwise get sent by the relevant C functions to `stdout`.

I would like the option of redirecting this data to a file stream or to standard output within the C++ application, if possible.

How might I do this? Can I leave my C code as-is and redirect `stdout` from within the C++ code?

**EDIT**

I can edit the C functions in question, so that a file pointer or descriptor is an argument. Would this help, being able to pass in where the output goes? What's unclear to me is how I would translate C++ IO and C IO.  I can't pass in a C++ `iostream` to a C function, or can I?

Comment: On some systems (notably Linux), `stdout` from C and `std::cout` from C++ are "in sync". And you can always use `<cstdio>` header in C++ code to get the C notion of `stdout`.

Comment: So if I set `FILE *fp = stdout` and have a C function `foo(FILE *fp)` that spits out data to `stdout`, then what would I do to redirect output from `std::cout` to an output stream that is either (still) `std::cout` or a file output stream?

Comment: A C function don't know about C++ `std::cout` ! But see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/io_and_c.html

Comment: Are you on Unix / Linux / MacOS? Also, is it sufficient to just redirect stdout to a file rather than somehow combining it with a C++ stream?

Comment: What about passing into the library one end of a socket and simply writing to that socket and read it again on the client side?

Comment: I am on Linux and OS X. My C code is POSIX- and GNU99-compliant and compiles fine on both platforms. I need to send the C function's output to either `stdout` (or the C++ equivalent `std::cout`) or to a file.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that my answer is judged so harshly. I've tried updating it after the edits to the question, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), and run the C program as a stand-alone process with its stdout connected to the input end of the pipe. Your C++ program then needs to read from the output end of the pipe, and it will then get all the output from the C process.

**UPDATE:** I re-read the question a bit more after the downvotes and comments. I (now) realize the C code is running as a library, i.e. linked into the same executable as the C++ code.

I don't think you can forcibly redirect stdout for the C code without affecting the C++'s program's output stream at the same time, which seems like a very high price to pay in order to have a library.

I still think the solution is to "sandbox" the C code in a process of its own, with a redirected output that you can then read as desired. It would of course be better to re-write the C functionality to `return` results instead of printing them, but I assume that's not an option.

You say that the C code uses `fprintf()`, i.e. the variant with an explicit file handle, so perhaps you can use that and make it accept a `FILE *` from the outside, in which case you can feed it a pipe without having to subprocess it.

Very interested in seeing other answers, perhaps there's an approach I'm missing.

**UPDATE 2**: If you have the chance to control which `FILE *` you pass into the C library, then it's easy:

- To have the output appear with the C++ program's ordinary output, just pass in `stdout`.
- To capture the output to a file, `fopen()` the file and pass in the resulting `FILE *`.

If you want to do *both* at the same time, that's a bit more troublesome, again. In that case I would, again, recommend a pipe or socket so that the C++ side is responsible for reading out the output generated by the C library, and do what it wishes with it.

Comment: But Alex Reynolds writes about his C *library*, not a C program!

Comment: This is not what I'm after. I'm writing a library, so it all needs to be done within the application.

Comment: **Running the C program separately with pipes and sockets is not what I am after.** I'm am writing a **library**, so it all needs to be done with the application.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment I mentioned that C++ `std::cout` and C `stdout` are related in a tricky way, and that you can use `stdout` in C++ by including `<cstdio>`. I also gave the following link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/io_and_c.html

However, you might consider changing the API of your library, and provide functions which write to a user supplied stream, and/or to a user supplied file path.

On Linux, you might also use [open_memstream](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream) or [fopencookie](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopencookie)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, no, at least with standard conforming code.

What could be related is std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio which ensures that IO made on some C++ streams are correctly synchronized with IO make of C streams. So stdout is synchronized with cout, stdin with cin and stderr width cerr. But that isn't designed to allow changing the streambuf in cout and have the change propagated to stdout (which is how I understood your request), and I'm far from sure on the intented effect if you do a freopen on stdout.